# Is this a clean way to withdraw from a contract in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have been looking high and low about how to withdraw the funds from an Ethereum contract with no prevail. The `Remix` editor is giving the warning that this function may cause an infinite loop.

`Gas requirement of function KOTH.cleanTheKingsChest() high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)`

And...
Should I use `Open-Zeppelin's` safe math for this function?

```
function cleanTheKingsChest() public isOwner {
  uint bal = address(this).balance;
  address(owner).transfer(bal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will transfer all ether held by the contract to the owner’s address. There is no issue with the way you’re doing it.

The reason for the warning is because you are making a call out to another address. That address could itself be a contract with a custom defined `transfer` or fallback function (if no `transfer` method is defined). Since Remix doesn’t know what that implementation may do, it’ can’t estimate the gas usage. This isn’t a concern since `transfer` calls are limited to a 2100 gas stipend.

You don’t *need* `SafeMath` for that function since you’re not doing anything that can cause an overflow. However, in general, it’s a good idea to use it.